# How to give a link to a directory in HTML?

Tags: html, file, directory

My problem is giving a link to a directory, in an inner network. It is working for IE 6 but i need to do this for especially for IE7 and IE8.

My internal Link is like that: \CompName\Report\

I tried to do this with : file://.... but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to use the [`file` URI schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) and it does respect relative paths.

They are however, platform specific, so may only work on one of windows/mac/linux.

Make sure you get the relative path correctly.

```
file://CompName/Report
```

You may need to double up any `/` for each "\" you have - UNC paths start with `\\`, so this would translate to `////`, so:

```
file://///CompName/Report
```

Should work, assuming it is a shared directory on a computer called `CompName` and that you have the correct permissions to access it.

Comment: the permissions are proper. It is not issue here trust me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

> file://///CompName/Report/

Note that IE8 (and I believe IE7 as well) will open the link in an *explorer* window (not Internet Explorer).

Comment: well, when i tried this it didn't open in a explorer window but in a internet explorer window and it said there is no such internet address etc. :S. It didn't make the trick for me yet.

Comment: There must be something specific about your configuration, then, because it works fine for me (tested with IE8 on Windows 7)